# What's the relationship between client and workspace in perforce?

Tags: perforce

Yes, the company i'm working for is still using perforce.
Workspace is a set of files in local.
But what's the relationship between p4 client and workspace pls ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're essentially synonyms.  "Client" is usually shorthand for "client workspace".  Which is the only kind of workspace there is.  So "client" = "workspace".

Related concepts include:

- **Client spec**: the specification form for a workspace.  This defines the:

  - **Client root**: the root folder of the workspace
  - **Client view**: the mapping between the workspace and the server repository (depots)
  - **Client options**: stuff like `noclobber` and `rmdir` that affect how you sync files
- **Local files**: all of the files that are in your workspace
- **Client "have list"**: the server's records of which depot revisions your local files correspond to

If someone says just "client" or "workspace", they could be talking about the "workspace" as an aggregation of all of the above data, or they could be talking about the **local files**, or they could be talking about the **client spec**.  Sometimes it might even be the **client application** (e.g. P4V, P4, or whatever you use to talk to the server and manage your workspace).  It's usually pretty obvious from context.

Typically, P4V uses the term "workspace" whereas the command line client application (and the server API, which the CLI is a thin wrapper around) uses the term "client".